# How can I get the metadata from mp3 files and put them into HTML format?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mp3

I want to get the ID3 metadata and put them into a HTML format.

The problem that I have is that I don't know almost anything about JavaScript/PHP or any other languages other than HTML and CSS, so basically I am having a hard time trying to find anything that I can understand about this topic.

I am basically trying to find a way to put this metadata: artist, album, genre, duration, year, track, title. About the duration if there is only one track for example, the track's duration is 5 minutes then what if there are 5 tracks, I would like to basically combine the whole duration of those tracks and if each track is 5 minutes long then the outcome would be 25 minutes. Also about the track number I don't know if it's possible to have each track number and by their side the track's title so if that's possible it would be nice to have too.

Here is the HTML format that I have created. I'll explain almost everything that is on the code. And also when this is done I'll show you what it would look like.

```
      <div class="line-content"> <!-- PLACEHOLDER Collapsible -->
        <div name="PLACEHOLDER">
          <button type="button" class="collapsible button"><img class="limg" src="forsongstab/covers/PLACEHOLDER.jpeg">PLACEHOLDER</button>
          <div class="content">
            <p><img class="fimg" src="forsongstab/covers/PLACEHOLDER.jpeg">
              <table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr>
                <td>Artist/Band:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Album:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Gerne:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Duration:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Release Date:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td>PLACEHOLDER</td>
              </tr></table>
              <table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr><td>
                01. PLACEHOLDER<br>
              </td></tr></table>
            <p class="pl40"><a href="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip" download="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip">Download the whole Album.</a></p></p>
          </div><p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Okay so you can see a lot of `PLACEHOLDER` words and that's basically where all the metadata would go.

The `<div class="line-content">` is for a pagination and since there are hundreds of albums it is needed.

The `<!-- PLACEHOLDER Collapsible -->` is just a comment so it can be easily seen in code and tell apart from the other albums. In this PLACERHOLDER the name of the artist and the album will go. For example `<!-- 1000mods - Vultures Collapsible -->`, the name 1000mods is an artist/band (doesn't really matter) and the name Vultures is the name of the album.

The `<div name="PLACEHOLDER">` is also like the comment but it's just to keep things in a bit of a balance without the need of a comment but still necessary. Also in the PLACERHOLDER the input will be the same as the comment.

The `<button type="button" class="collapsible button"><img class="limg" src="forsongstab/covers/PLACERHOLDER.jpeg">PLACERHOLDER</button>` has many parts so let me expalin. the `<button>` is for the collapsible. Now the other two PLACERHOLDERS need to have the same name as the the comment did, so basically having both artist/band and album name as seen in the example previously.

The `<div class="content">` is for the collapsible.

The `<p><img class="fimg" src="forsongstab/covers/PLACEHOLDER.jpeg">` just the same as the others, have to change the PLACEHOLDER to the artist/band and album name.

Now basically you can see a table and I think it's clear what goes where but I'll still expalin it.

On the first row we have the Artist/Band: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the artist metadata.

On the second row we have the Album: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the album metadata.

On the third row we have the Gerne: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the gerne metadata.

On the fourth row we have the Duration: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the duration of all the tracks on that specific album.

On the fifth row we have the Release Date: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the year metadata.

On the sixth and last row we have the Size: and on that PLACEHOLDER we add the total size of the tracks in the album and by size I mean MB.

Now the next table will be used to have the track number and titles in a place. You can see the 01. which will be the number of the track, then it should have a normal space for the name to stand out and not be a continuous line of blurry text and then it should have a `<br>` (even it's just one track).

The `<p class="pl40"><a href="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip" download="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip">Download the whole Album.</a></p></p>` has also many parts so let me explain them aswell. The `<p class="p140">`  is basically to add a style to that text. The `<a href="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip" download="forsongstab/zips/PLACEHOLDER.zip">` on these PLACEHOLDERS the artist/band and album names will go as shown in the comment way up there. The text and the `</a></p></p>` doesn't bother us at all so we will leave it there.

And now the other `</div>` are just closing the other divs and that paragraph that seems to be out of place is just to add some space between collapsibles.

Here is what it should look like after all this.

```
      <div class="line-content"> <!-- 1000mods - Vultures Collapsible -->
        <div name="1000mods - Vultures">
          <button type="button" class="collapsible button"><img class="limg" src="forsongstab/covers/1000mods - Vultures.jpeg">1000mods - Vultures</button>
          <div class="content">
            <p><img class="fimg" src="forsongstab/covers/1000mods - Vultures.jpeg">
              <table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr>
                <td>Artist/Band:</td>
                <td>1000mods</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Album:</td>
                <td>Vultures</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Gerne:</td>
                <td>Stoner Rock</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Duration:</td>
                <td>00:38:14</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Release Date:</td>
                <td>2014</td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td>69,1 MB</td>
              </tr></table>
              <table class="pl5 lh1-4"><tr><td>
                01. Claws<br>
                02. Big Beautiful<br>
                03. She<br>
                04. Horses Green<br>
                05. Low<br>
                06. Vultures<br>
                07. Modesty<br>
                08. Reverb of the New World<br>
              </td></tr></table>
            <p class="pl40"><a href="forsongstab/zips/1000mods - Vultures.zip" download="forsongstab/zips/1000mods - Vultures.zip">Download the whole Album.</a></p></p>
          </div><p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now the problem is that I don't know if anyone has a way to actually make something that can help me with this nor explain it to me how to actually code something like this. So if anyone actually knows how to find a way to make JavaScript for this or have a program that can help me I would appreciate very much.

Thank you for your help and your patience for reading all this. If you got any questions just comment them here and I'll try my best to reply and find an answer.

Comment: I see you mentioned php but the tag isnt there but you could use ffmpeg extension for php

Comment: I don't really know if it could have a solution to the problem nor do i know how to code in such a language but I thought there could be a solution with language so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Not with JavaScript. With php should be easy.

---

It's not as much easy as id3v1 is limited and id3v2 is ... let's say it needs data storage, it cannot be read dynamically*.
I decided to go with id3v1.1 - now all you need is a server with a php7 parser and a favicon. Instructions inside. Copy the php script and save as text file index.php utf-8 with BOM or not (irrelevant). Just like that, you can use Notepad. Place this file on the server with style.css and favicon.ico and run - that is, type the address into the browser and voilà.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="robots" content="none">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"><title>mp3</title></head><body>
<?php
function readid3($file){
    $genre = [ 'Blues', 'Classic rock', 'Country', 'Dance', 'Disco', 'Funk', 'Grunge', 'Hip-Hop', 'Jazz', 'Metal', 'New Age', 'Oldies', 'Other', 'Pop', 'Rhythm and Blues', 'Rap', 'Reggae', 'Rock', 'Techno', 'Industrial', 'Alternative', 'Ska', 'Death metal', 'Pranks', 'Soundtrack', 'Euro-Techno', 'Ambient', 'Trip-Hop', 'Vocal', 'Jazz & Funk', 'Fusion', 'Trance', 'Classical', 'Instrumental', 'Acid', 'House', 'Game', 'Sound clip', 'Gospel', 'Noise', 'Alternative Rock', 'Bass', 'Soul', 'Punk', 'Space', 'Meditative', 'Instrumental Pop', 'Instrumental Rock', 'Ethnic', 'Gothic', 'Darkwave', 'Techno-Industrial', 'Electronic', 'Pop-Folk', 'Eurodance', 'Dream', 'Southern Rock', 'Comedy', 'Cult', 'Gangsta', 'Top 40', 'Christian Rap', 'Pop/Funk', 'Jungle', 'Native US', 'Cabaret', 'New Wave', 'Psychedelic', 'Rave', 'Show tunes', 'Trailer', 'Lo-Fi', 'Tribal', 'Acid Punk', 'Acid Jazz', 'Polka', 'Retro', 'Musical', "Rock 'n' Roll", 'Hard rock' ];    
    $f = fopen("./mp3/$file",'rb');
    fseek($f, -128, SEEK_END);  
    $id3 = fread($f,128);
    fclose($f);
    $meta = unpack("a3header/a30title/a30artist/a30album/a4year/a28comment/a1zero/c1track/c1genre", preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', ' ', $id3));
    $meta = array_map(trim,$meta);
    $meta[genre] = $genre[$meta[genre]];
    return($meta);}
function start(){
    $once = 10;
    $dir = './mp3';
    $cover = './cover';
    $page = $_GET[page] ?? 1;
    $stop = $page*$once;
    $start = $stop - $once;
    foreach([$dir, $cover] as $val){    is_dir($val) ? '' : mkdir($val);}
    $mp3 = array_slice(scandir($dir),2);
    $count = count($mp3);
    if($count < 1){ echo"<p>You have no files in the $dir directiory</p><p>To display cover art, place file mp3_file_name.jpg in the $cover directory</p>";}
    else{
        foreach($mp3 as $key=>$val){
            if(($key >= $start) && ($key < $stop)){
                $m = readid3($val);
                $img = strtr($val,['mp3'=>'jpg']);
                $m[size] = round(filesize("$dir/$val")/1048576,2).' MB';
                echo"<details><summary><b>$m[title]</b><b>$m[artist]</b><b>$m[album]</b></summary>\r\n<figure><img src=\"$cover/$img\" alt=\"cover\">\r\n";
                echo"<figcaption><a download=\"$val\" href=\"$val\">download</a>\r\n</figcaption></figure><table>\r\n";
                foreach([title, artist, album, genre, year, track, size, comment] as $val){ echo    "<tr><th>$val</th><td>$m[$val]</td></tr>\r\n";}
                echo"</table></details>\r\n";}}
        foreach(range(1,(int)ceil($count/$once)) as $val){  echo"<a href=\"?page=$val\">$val</a>";}}}
start();
?></body></html>
```

style.css

```
*{ box-sizing: border-box; outline: 0}
body{ text-align: center; color: #013; padding-top: 5vh;  background: #fff}
a{ text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; margin: 10px 20px; color: inherit; background: linear-gradient(to top, #468, #fff, #79b);border-radius: 20px; padding: 15px;}
a:not([download]){ border-radius: 50%; width: 50px}
details{ border: 1px solid #abd; margin: 2vh auto}
summary{ display: block; background: #def; padding: 20px 10px; background: linear-gradient(to top, #468, #fff, #79b);}
summary b{ font: inherit; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 32%; }
details:hover b{ font-weight: bold}
figure, table{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 5px 2vw}
img{ max-width: 100%}
th, td{ padding: 5px 10px}
th{ width: auto; color: #456; font: normal normal 0.9em sans-serif}
```

It's not exactly as you wanted - without data storage it is not possible to combine tracks into an album and the duration has to be calculated and can't be done dynamically*.
.* cannot be done dynamically - theoretically possible, but it would be the slowest site in the world and a server killer.

Comment: The name of the artist and the album's name I used are not the ones that I have downloaded. It's just going to be for a group of friends and since one of them makes a lot of music, I will have it all in one place for our ground of friends to either download and listen to it whenever they want. It's not something illigal and I live in Europe too so it is just for friends and people that are close to me.

Comment: @Awexu I sent the code. See how it works, I hope it's enough. Learn php and more solutions will be available